# In C++, close a static file stream inside a class member function

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program (developed in Visual C++ 2017) that need to output a lot of lines to files. Below are simplified version just to illustrate the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
public:
    void output(int a){
        static ofstream out("a.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
        out<<a<<"\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        t.output(i);
    }

    t.~Test();

    remove("a.txt");
}
```

**The remove("a.txt") never works. I understand that the text file is never properly closed. I explicitly call the t.~Test() in hope it will close the static ofstream but it seems id does not work.**

**The reason to make the ofstream static is it significantly improve the performance of my production code since I assume it just open the file one time and use it instead of open and close the file for each call**

**I know the design is bad, but this is from legacy code and I am reluctant to change the function signature.**

Is there a simple way to make this work without changing the "out" function signature? Thanks

Comment: Don't make it a local static variable, make it a instance variable.

Comment: Any reason why you call the destructor explicitely: `t.~Test();`? That's rarely a good idea.

Comment: The life-time of local static variables is the life-time of the program. And the destructor can't close it since it doesn't know anything about local variables in other functions. Perhaps the stream should be a (non-static) *member* variable instead? Perhaps you need to step back to your design and think a little about what you need?

Comment: Another option is to switch to Linux, of course. The file will be perfectly removable, on Linux.

Comment: @tkausl, that is a good idea and I know it will work. Just curious keeping the current design, it there a way to make it work? Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to make it work. Not on MS-Windows, at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I explicitly call the destructor to see if it can close the local static variable, but it turns out it does not. Thanks.

Comment: @user11594134 Use curly braces instead of calling the destructor to shorten it's lifetime.

Comment: @user11594134 Destructors are for instances of classes, not `static`.  Second, there is no reason to call the destructor in your case.

Comment: By the way, since you open the file in append mode, why not make the stream variable *non* static? Then the file will be opened and *closed* each call to the function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, putting the ofstream to a class variable is an obvious solution. It is nice to learn that the life-time of static variable is the life-time of the program. That way, use as a class variable or passing the stream as a reference might be the only options. I have legacy code that is way I do not want to change the signature. As for static, it significantly improve the performance since it just open the stream once and keep using it for each line

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, give you an example, in my production code, using ofstream only use 30% of CPU, using static ofstream use 95%. I guess without static, each out function call will open the file, close it and this seem to cost a lot of I/O time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I use OpenMP and it would say abut several hundred lines per second. I think you already answer that question with the life-time of static variable. I may have to put in as a class variable. Would you mind post that to the answer section instead of comment. Thanks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thanks so much, it is nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The life-time of a local static variable is the life-time of the program itself. It will not be destructed until the program exits.

One possible way to go around your problem could be to use a member variable in the class instead. Open the stream in the constructor, and close it in the destructor. If multiple objects of the class needs to share the stream them make it a `static` member variable which is opened by its definition (remember that `static` member variables might need separate declaration and definition).

Comment: Thanks. It is nice to know the life-time of static variable is the whole program. It seems that I have to change the design.